# Which is the relationship between weak convergence and pointwise convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In one of my indipendent works at functional analysis course have to come up with an explicit way of telling which is the relationshpip between weak and pointwise convergence for $C(K)$ where $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space. I searched some articles but didn't find anything which is enough helpfull. The theory behind is kind of complicated and I don't think I have the necessary background to understand it. Can somebody guide me to get to the right point? Till now I have been working with Eberlein-Smulian theorem and weak compactness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about convergence of *sequences*? Without thinking about it further I don't know what happens for convergence of nets, because the proof below (from Proposition 19.3.1 of Semadeni's classic book *Banach spaces of continuous functions*) uses the dominated convergence theorem (which is proved in Semadeni's book as Theorem 19.2.6, but also on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)), which for all I know might not have an analogue for nets.

Besides the dominated convergence theorem, the following proof uses also the principle of uniform boundedness and the Riesz representation theorem (Theorem 18.4.1 in Semadeni's book).

*Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $f\in C(K)$ and
$(f_n)$ a sequence in $C(K)$. The following are equivalent:*

1. *$f_n$ converges weakly to $f$.*
2. *$f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ and $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert f_n\Vert<\infty$.*

Proof: If $(1)$ holds, then for each $k\in K$ we have $f_n(k) = \delta_k(f_n)\longrightarrow \delta_k(f) = f(k)$, so that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$. Moreover, the fact that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert f_n\Vert<\infty$ follows from the principle of uniform boundedness. Thus $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$.

Conversely, suppose $(2)$ holds and let $x^\ast\in C(K)^\ast$. Then, by the Riesz representation theorem, there exists a unique Radon measure $\mu_{x^\ast}$ on $K$ such that
$$
x^\ast(g) = \int_K g \,d\mu_{x^\ast}
$$
for every $g\in C(K)$. Moreover, the functions $f_n$ are dominated by the constant function $h: K\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $h(k) = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert f_n\Vert$ for every $k\in K$; that is, $\vert f_n(k)\vert\leq h(k)$ for every $k\in K$. It follows then by the dominated convergence theorem that for every $x^\ast\in C(K)$ we have
$$
x^\ast(f_n) = \int_K f_n \,d\mu_{x^\ast} \longrightarrow \int_K f \,d\mu_{x^\ast} = x^\ast(f)\,.
$$
Since $x^\ast$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$, hence $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$.

Comment: This seems really solid, yet so does the post above. I've spent the past 30 minutes trying to resolve why they come to different conclusions. By any chance can you see why this is? EDIT: Ah I think I just realized why; you have the condition that the $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mid\mid f_n \mid\mid < \infty$ and I'm guessing the function used above doesn't have this property, looking at it now. Let me know if you find it to be a different issue.

Comment: You're right about it being the uniform boundedness that makes the difference. In the example from the other answer, we have $f_n(1/n)=n/e$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate! Great answer!

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Incidentally, (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) also follows from Uniform boundedness, and the fact that the extreme points of the closed unit ball of $C(X)^{\ast}$ are the Dirac-delta measures (ie. you can prove this without Dominated convergence :)

Answer (score 3):

A sequence $f_n \in C(K)$ converges weakly to $f\in C(K)$ if
$$
w(f_n) \to w(f) \quad\forall w\in C(K)^{\ast}
$$
In particular, if $x \in K$, then $w_x \in C(K)^{\ast}$, where
$$
w_x(f) := f(x)
$$
Hence, if $f_n \xrightarrow{w} f$, then
$$
f_n(x) \to f(x) \quad\forall x\in K
$$
Hence, $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise.

---

The converse is not true, however. Take $K = [0,1]$ and
$$
f_n(x) = n^2xe^{-nx} \text{ and } f \equiv 0
$$
Then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. However, if
$$
w(f) := \int_0^1 f(x)dx
$$
then $w\in C(K)^{\ast}$ and
$$
w(f_n) = 1 - (1/e^n) - (n/e^n)
$$
So
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} w(f_n) = 1 \neq 0 = w(f)
$$
Hence, $f_n$ does not converge weakly to $f$.

Comment: The same connection between two types of convergences is true when we consider the space of continuous linear functions in general, isn't it? Why do we ask $K$ to be compact and Hausdorff?  Could you recommend me any book where I can go into more depth? I need to cite the sources I use.